# Windows Server 2016 on Azure is not activated

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have deployed an instance of Windows Server 2016 (with containers) on Azure. When I start the machine I see a message in the right-bottom that Windows hasn't been activated.

Also the settings show that Windows is not activated:
[image: Windows not activated]

I would guess that these Azure provided images have already been activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to resize your VM to other size.

If it does not work, I suggest you refer this official article about [troubleshooting Windows activation failures on Azure VMs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2014/12/23/troubleshooting-windows-activation-failures-on-azure-vms/).